# Use LG UltraFine 4K with PS4 Pro (And probably Xbox One X)

Tags: ps4, monitor

I'm interested in getting one of these displays (21.5 inch 4k variant) to replace my old 1440p one. I have also pre-ordered an Xbox One X and would like to know if it's gonna work with the display.

As the Xbox One X has barely started shipping I'm not expecting people to have tested this configuration yet but has anyone tried to get the PS4 Pro working with one of these? If it works with the PS4 Pro (through an adapter of course) without performance hits then it should already work with Xbox X.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for it not to work is just a monitor, as long as you have the proper adaptor you will be fine.

(4k in a 21.5" display is a bit too much thou, there is no point in processing extra pixels that you can barely see, I would suggest 24" or 27" at least)

*edit*

there is some discussion here:https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/5fan7e/lg_ultrafine_4k_compatible_with_windows_10_on_a_pc/

Basically its a usb type c monitor. even being designer thinking in Apple products it still has to respect the protocol. You just need to make sure to get the right cable and the right adaptor. (not every cable or adaptor supports 4k)

Plus apparently some feature such as the light sensor seem not to work in windows 10 because there are no drivers for it.

Comment: this is a possible adaptor https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/phones-broadband-and-sat-nav/mobile-phones-and-accessories/mobile-accessories/sandstrom-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter-10156292-pdt.html?istCompanyId=bec25c7e-cbcd-460d-81d5-a25372d2e3d7&istItemId=xmttpalwlw&istBid=tztx&srcid=198&cmpid=ppc~gg~1022%20(PLA)%20PC%20COMPONENTS%20-%20Adaptive~1022%20(PLA)%20PC%20COMPONENTS%20-%20Adaptive%20ad%20group~Exact&mctag=gg_goog_7904&kwid=GOOGLE&device=c&ds_kids=92700027890037021&PLA=1&tgtid=1022%20(PLA)%20PC%20COMPONENTS%20-%20Adaptive&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvtiHy5ax1wIViBbTCh30WA4MEAQYBSABEgI0ffD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Thanks for the link but because it's an Apple product and the brand isn't really known for cross-compatibility, I wan't to see a working example beforehand. 4k in 21.5" gives a very decent dpi which will help things (especially text) look crisp and I appreciate that as I'm a developer

Comment: there is some info online https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/5fan7e/lg_ultrafine_4k_compatible_with_windows_10_on_a_pc/

Comment: I agree with your answer, but 4k in a small monitor does have its advantages. I have a 17" laptop with a 4k screen (I didn't need the 4k but on discount it was literally cheaper than its 1080p brother), and I like the finer detail you can get. Not so much from games (graphics can't support 4k), but working with the computer on a day to day basis is nice in 4k.

Comment: @RapazAtrevido seems it's not likely to work, but I still like to hear someone say "I tried it on PS4 Pro/Xbox One X and it didn't/did work".

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Ultrafine 21.5 monitor is not working with ps4 pro via typec-hdmi adapter from Apple https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b

It looks like adapter only works in one side if we connect external monitor via hdmi-hdmi cable but doesn't in opposite site if we put adapter to monitor(ultrafine) and connect HDMI-to-HDMI cable from PS4.

Probably that can works with typeC-to-Hdmi cable without adapters, but really not sure, and not ready to buy cable additionally.

**Edit:** based on https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/7z17jq/connect_lg_ultrafine_display_4k5k_to_a_ps4_or/ it doesn't work even via typeC-to-HDMI cable.